# typescript minimal allowed number in parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like:

```
function getBlogs(limit?: number) { ... }
```

The `limit` can only be a positive integer and it cant be `0`.

How do i tell typescript that this number can only be greater then 0?

Comment: No it's not possible with TypeScript

Comment: While jcalz's answer provides a few roundabout ways to approach this, keep in mind that solving this for the most generic case without manual annotations would be equal to the halting problem.

Comment: @Etheryte can you elaborate about *which* “most generic case” is equivalent to the halting problem?  Anything I can think of seems like you can say the same thing about almost any programming question, so maybe I’m missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open suggestion, [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) to support "range types" where you could say something like, say,  `type PositiveWholeNumbers = 1..9999999` to represent your type.  There's also a (closed) suggestion [microsoft/TypeScript#4639](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4639) to support `int` and `uint`-like types, which could also possibly work here.  Sadly, neither of these are implemented, so if you want to pursue this in the type system you need to do something else.

---

If there's a reasonably small upper limit (in the thousands *at most*), you can manually generate a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of the allowable values and shove it in a library file somewhere.  This can be done programmatically so you don't have to physically type it out, but it's the same as if you did:

```
// Evaluate the following in JS and copy into your code somewhere
// "type AllowableValues = "+
//   Array.from({length: 5000}, (x, i) => String(i+1)+((i+1)%100?"":"\n")).join(" | ")+";";
// which produces:

type AllowableValues = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | // and so on

function getBlogs(limit?: AllowableValues) {
  console.log((limit || 0).toFixed());
}
```

This will work in the sense that the compiler will see that `limit` is some numeric value in the union (or `undefined`), and calling `getBlogs()` with a numeric argument will be validated against it:

```
getBlogs(100); // okay
getBlogs(1); // okay
getBlogs(1.5); // error!
// ----> ~~~
// Argument of type '1.5' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 1 | 2 | 3 | ...
getBlogs(0); // error!
// ----> ~
// Argument of type '0' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 1 | 2 | 3 | ...
getBlogs(-4);
// ----> ~~
// Argument of type '-4' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 1 | 2 | 3 | ...
```

Of course anything outside the range will fail:

```
getBlogs(1234567); // error (too big)
getBlogs(1e100); // error (too big)
```

And this really only works when people call `getBlogs()` with some numeric literal.  Mathematical operations tend to produce `number`, which is too wide to be validated:

```
getBlogs(3+1); // error: safe but the compiler can't tell
```

Also I've noticed that big unions like the above bog things down enough to make my IDE sluggish, so I'd really only recommend doing this for numbers up to several hundred.

---

Another possibility is to make `getBlogs()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function where the argument is validated to make sure it's a positive whole number.  You can, I think, get this done in TypeScript 4.1 using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

```
type AsPositiveWholeNumber<N extends number> =
  N extends 0 ? PositiveWholeNumber :
  number extends N ? PositiveWholeNumber :
  `${N}` extends `${infer F}${"." | "-"}${infer L}` ?
  PositiveWholeNumber : N

type PositiveWholeNumber = {
  ["Please choose a value that is a positive whole number"]: number
} & number

function getBlogs<N extends number>(limit?: AsPositiveWholeNumber<N>) {
  console.log((limit || 0).toFixed());
}
```

Here, the `getBlogs()` function accepts a `limit` parameter of type `AsPositiveWholeNumber<N>`, where `N` is a `number`-constrained type parameter inferred by the value of `limit` passed in.  The `AsPositiveWholeNumber<N>` type is designed so that if `N` is a positive whole number, then `AsPositiveWholeNumber<N>` will just be `N`.  Otherwise, it will be `PositiveWholeNumber`, a dummy type whose purpose is to give the user a plausibly useful error message.

The important work is done inside `AsPositiveWholeNumber<N>`.  First we make sure that `N` is neither `number` nor `0`.  Then we convert it to a string via the template literal type `` `${N}` `` and then make sure that this string version of `N` contains no `"."` or `"-"` characters. This should mostly distinguish positive whole numbers from other numbers, at least until we get to *huge* values which are integers but whose string representation is rendered in exponential notation with a decimal point  (such as `1.23456789e+23`).

Let's see if it works:

```
getBlogs(100); // okay
getBlogs(1); // okay
getBlogs(1.5); // error!
// ----> ~~~
// Argument of type '1.5' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'PositiveWholeNumber | undefined'
getBlogs(0); // error!
// ----> ~
// Argument of type '0' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'PositiveWholeNumber | undefined'
getBlogs(-4);
// ----> ~~
// Argument of type '-4' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'PositiveWholeNumber | undefined'

getBlogs(1234567); // okay
getBlogs(1e100); // okay, but
getBlogs(11e98); // error: becomes 1.1e+99
getBlogs(3 + 1); // error: safe but the compiler can't tell
```

So that works also.  It has the same problem where you need to call `getBlogs()` with a numeric literal and that any `number`-typed parameter will not be accepted.  This solution definitely has more weird moving parts than the pure union, so I'm not sure I'd really recommend this in any production code.  But I did want to show how close TypeScript can currently get to your desired behavior.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Comment: Or you could use a tagged literal type and a type guard / constructor - that would let you pass around `PositiveInteger`s (but wouldn't let you provide positive integers inline).